# CLion: Select different encoding for file extension

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, clion

I have a project where most files are utf-8 encoded, but there is a specific file type which must be in ISO-8859-1 encoding and these files have a specific extension.

Is there a way to configure CLion in such a way that these files are open with the correct encoding?

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html#file-encoding-settings

Encoding could be set for a path, but not for files with extension:
[image: file encoding IntelliJ IDEA]

Workaround is to use BOM (for XML, HTML and others), or set encoding per file:
[image]